# looping javascript action issue

Tags: javascript, loops, timeline

I have a timeline that loops posts and allows for users to comment on each post. After entering the comment it is meant to prepend to the post in which the comment is made. Problem now is that it prepends to the very first post. This means that this prepend action is not following the loop.

Add comment function

```
<!--Function to add comment-->
var msg2 = $("#feeds li #comment-form #comment");
var msg = $("#feeds #comment-form #hidden");
var textarea = $('#comment');
$('.comment-btn').on("click",function(event) {
    var one = $(this).parent().find(msg2).val();
    var two = $(this).parent().find(msg).val();

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_comment.php",
        data: "msg2="+ one +"&msg=" + two,
        msg: "Checking...",
            success: function(data){
    $('#feeds li #comment-form').parent().find('textarea').val("");
    updateComment();
            }
        });
});
```

And this is the updateComment function

```
<!--Function to update the comment feed-->
function updateComment(){
    var id = 0;
    id = $('#feeds li #other-comments').attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        'url' : 'comment.php',
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : {
            'latest_comment_time' : id
        },
        success : function(data){
            if(id != 0){
                $('#sub-comments').prepend(data);
            }
        }
    }) 
}
```

**Edited**

html

```
                    <div id='comments'>
                <form action='' id="comment-form" method="post">
                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Add comment..."></textarea>
                <input type="button" class='comment-btn' value='Send'>
                <input type="hidden" name="msg" value="<?=$item['msg_id']?>" id="hidden">
                </form>
                <div id="sub-comments">
                <?php require('comment.php');?>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Note: the 'feeds li' is for the looping post.

Comment: post please your HTML as well

Comment: Is that html script the one which is in the loop?

Comment: So that means all your subcomments under each comment have id "sub-comment". That's probably your issue.

Comment: @lombausch what do you recommend then?

Comment: sorry for delay, you should add counter in the loop and attach it to the id selector for subcomments to ensure unique id